# Adding Custom Lint Rules

Tags: java, android, lint

I am following the tutorial on this(http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules) page.
I am stuck at the step:

```
lint --show MyId
```

I get the following error message, any ideas?

> Could not load custom rule jar file
>   /Users/me/.android/lint/CustomLintRule.jar
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Issue.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Category;ILcom/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Severity;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/EnumSet;)Lcom/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Issue;
>     at googleio.demo.MyDetector.(MyDetector.java:16)    at
>   googleio.demo.MyIssueRegistry.getIssues(MyIssueRegistry.java:15)  at
>   com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry.(JarFileIssueRegistry.java:93)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry.get(JarFileIssueRegistry.java:70)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.addCustomLintRules(LintClient.java:911)
>     at com.android.tools.lint.Main.getGlobalRegistry(Main.java:642)     at
>   com.android.tools.lint.Main.run(Main.java:204)    at
>   com.android.tools.lint.Main.main(Main.java:113) Invalid id or category
>   "MyId".

Comment: Looks like you're compiling against one version of the API and running against another. See the note in the create issue section about using Tools 22.

Comment: I compiled the jar with lint-api-23.0.2.jar and also my lint version 23.0.2 when i check at my teerminal by lint --version. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post the code you've got?  I am guessing you're calling the 7 argument version of #create since that's the one it can't find - but the Tools 22+ version takes 8 arguments, which means your classpath at build time might have something errant about it.

Comment: Actually i am using the exact same project on the http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules. So my code is,
 public static final Issue ISSUE = Issue.create(
            "MyId",
            "My brief summary of the issue",
            "My summary of what the detector looks for",
            "My longer explanation of the issue",
            Category.CORRECTNESS, 6, Severity.WARNING,
            new Implementation(MyDetector.class, Scope.RESOURCE_FILE_SCOPE));

Answer (score 1):

I was same too.

1. I'm using mac and AndroidStudio 0.8.6.
2. I exported "customrule.jar" in Eclipse using lint-api.jar in 
   "/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/lib".
3. Eclise project for the rule is compiled well with the lint-api.jar.
4. But, when I run "lint --show MyId", I got the same error.

So I downloaded adt-bundle and I tried with "lint-api.jar" in it and the error was gone.

I think "lint-api.jar" included in AndroidStudio is something wrong...

Comment: Hmm, i'll try that as soon as possible.

Comment: And, was this hint the solution for the problem?

Comment: Using the latest `lint-api.jar` e.g. from `android-sdk\tools\lib` has solved the issue for me as well.

This particular exception is caused by the API change some time ago. It's described on http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules under the section "Create Issue".

Comment: Using the lint-api.jar from adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702, still getting the same error.