# Custom-rule.jar not found or read

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I am following this [post](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules) about writing custom lint rules for android project.I have downloaded sample project and imported it in eclipse ,followed all the steps.I have placed jar in .android/lint directory

Now I executed following command

```
C:\Users\username>cd C:\Users\Users\.android\lint

C:\Users\username\.android\lint>custom-lint.jar

C:\Users\username\.android\lint>C:\Users\username\AndroidSetup
-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\lint --show "MyId"
```

This command produces following output :

```
Custom lint rule jar C:\Users\username\.android\lint\custom-lint.jar do
id registry manifest key (Lint-Registry).
Either the custom jar is invalid, or it uses an outdated API not supported this
Invalid id or category "MyId".
```

Please tell me what I have executed wrong here ?

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680418/adding-custom-lint-rules

Comment: not much help with this

Comment: The above link should be help you !